# I'm stumped at an error that appears whenever i try to create a database table from csv file

Tags: sqlite, csv, google-colaboratory, database-table

I've uploaded the CSV file in the session storage of Google Colab and tried to create a database table from that CSV file, but I always encounter the error below

```
with open('Cities.csv') as f: Cities = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0)
%sql drop table if exists Cities;
%sql persist Cities
```

ERROR

```
* sqlite://
  Done.
* sqlite://
  (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "persist": syntax error
  \[SQL: persist Cities\]
  (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```